# Is there a way to make <dot-tab> completion work in IPython with python namespace packages?

Tags: python, autocomplete, namespaces, ipython

I want to use tab-completion within the IPython repl interface.  This does not work with [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages).

Basically if you do "import mynamespace." is doesn't work until you type the full "mynamespace.mypackge".

I want the usual standard dot-tab in the repl to work for namespace packages.